# C++ IDE/ANSI compiler for Mac OSX?

Tags: c++

I am taking a c++ course at school and need an ANSI compliant compiler, i was planning on using Xcode but  know it is not ANSi compliant (or i believe so at least). Any tips o a good IDE/ANSI compliant compiler i can use on my Mac for this course? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you mean ANSI but which version of the ISO C++ standard? (The compiler with Xcode is C++03 compliant (well at least for a C++ course))

Comment: If there is a compiler they use on lab computers, or one they mentioned in class, that could help us narrow it down (or tell you how to get that one on your Mac.

Comment: What makes you think Xcode isn't ANSI C++ compliant? That's wrong...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Do you mean ANSI, as in ANSI C?</strike> You can go ahead and use Xcode, it has modes for the two common ANSI C dialects, c89 and c99.

If you're doing C++, the C++ compiler in Xcode also supports the common C++ standards, C++98, C++03. It also supports one of the most complete C++11 implementations available. However these standards aren't usually called 'ANSI C++' even though the American National Standards Institute does participate in the ISO standards setting process that creates them. But this is probably what is meant by your instructor.

<strike>If your instructor meant something else you'll have to provide more info, because as far as I'm aware "ANCI" is just gibberish in the context of C++.</strike>

Bottom line, Xcode will be fine.